# Is returning Optional overkill in StringUtils?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a custom StringUtils class in my project, I would like to return Optional, but I notice in Apache's String Utils they are not returning Optional.

In general, is it ok to return Optional in StringUtils? or it is an overkill?

Comment: StringUtils was written before (and used by code before) Java 8

Comment: Don’t use Apache’s String Utils as a template for software design. A lot of these methods are superfluous as their only difference to the already existing String methods is their questionable treatment of `null` arguments. I’d say, use `Optional` only if the operation truly may have no result, like when finding something. Don’t use it for turning `null` arguments to empty optionals.

Comment: @Holger interesting :) we have just removed this dependency from our code and let me tell that life is easier, at least for me. I don't have to understand those API anymore

Answer (score 5):

The point of Optional is to indicate that a function/method can have no return value (i.e. null). If that's your case, and returning Optional makes more sense than returning null (it does most of the time in my opinion), then go ahead.

Returning null is bad in general because it can cause unexpected bugs if you or someone else forgets to check for null in the future, so you should return a default value in most cases. One advantage that Optional gives you is the possibility to determine that default value dynamically through `orElse` or `orElseGet` and forces you to do it to get the value out of the Optional, preventing most `NullPointerException`s

Comment: And also, StringUtils pre-dates Optional